# Linux fork() command

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork, printf

I wrote a program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int returnVal = fork();
    printf("Return Value: %i\n", returnVal);
    return 1;
}
```

when I compile this and run, I get the following output
I have given only one printf statement then why do I see 2 prints. If I remove the print then nothing is printed.

```
alwin@alwin-desktop:~/Projects/Nix$ ./a.out 
Return Value: 5547
Return Value: 0
```

Comment: Are you sure you've read `man fork`?

Comment: You're using `fork`; what did you expect?

Comment: why is my question down voted???

Comment: Your question is downvoted because you did not bother reading the documentation, notably http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html ; and `fork` is not a command, it is a system call. I also suggest reading http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: FYI I did read the fork man page, I asked the question in the context of the program that I wrote. man page does not answer me that.

Comment: The documentation does say that `fork` returns (on success) both in the parent and in the child, etc... So by re-reading several times the documentation, you could have understood by yourself. In addition, there are many web tutorials about `fork` ....

Comment: Really new to Linux and Fork().. Google Landed me here rightly and I actually learnt more than I expected.. Don't know why this question was down voted so badly...just because the OP ignored 'man fork' ? question is indeed helpful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go through man command :-)

Check: [`pid_t fork(void);`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

> The `fork()` creates a new process by duplicating the calling process. The new process, referred to as the child, is **an exact duplicate of the calling process**, referred to as the parent.

DETAILS:: First you executed your code which created a child process. Now you have two processes executing the same piece of code. So TWO print statements, first of the Parent Process and second of the Child Process.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan :: Thanks for editing. I didn't know the Ctrl+Q option.

Answer (score 6):

The `printf` statement in your program is executed `twice`, because once fork is successful, the program is controlled by `two processes`(`child` and `parent` processes).So printf here, is executed by both child and parent processes

To avoid such behaviour, it is always good to have three different condition checks in program using fork()

```
int pid;
if((pid = fork()) == -1 )
{ //fork unsuccessful 
 }
else if ( pid > 0)
{ //This is parent
 }
else
{//This is child
 }
```

Comment: Your text needs improvements: 1) printf() prints the process id of the child and `0`. 2) child is not created with a pid of `0`. 3) error is indicated by a return of exactly `-1`.

Comment: @pmg Edited the answer based on your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`fork` creates a new process. So there are two processes which execute the next statement. The father process have `returnVal = 5547` (child process' PID) and the child process `returnVal = 0`.

> The `fork()` function shall create a new process. The new process (child process) shall be an exact copy of the calling process (parent process)

Comment: I know fork returns 2 values, but when I have given only one printf statement how come it prints it twice is my question

Comment: Cuz the child process again executes the same code. So it again prints a Return Value.